# Clone array of objects into itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, clone

This is my source array (e.g. with 20 elements):

```
var myArray= $('.my-selector').clone().toArray();
```

I want to clone the whole array into itself. The new array should have 40 elements (each element is existing "twice"). Like this:

```
myNewArray = myArray.concat($('.my-selector').clone().toArray())
```

But it seems that the new arrays elements are references to the original and no real clones.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What do you achieve by doing so?

Comment: can you provide us with an example ? or result that you want to achieve ?

Comment: Your question is `unclear`

Comment: Are you talking about JS arrays, or rows / cells of an HTMLTableElement?

Comment: Whished result: A jQuery selection is taken, its elements should be copied to another DOM part. But the elements should be copied several times to the new place.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal The reason you used `code formatting` there is unclear.

Comment: I‘ve edited the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer.**

@JKB, I have updated my answer based on your recent comment on my old answer. I think the code you have posted in your question is actually working fine. I am using 3 elements to demo this, instead of the original 20, but the same logic applies.

I have quoted you in code comments in the code snippets, from your original question, as well as your recent comment on my old answer. Please read through them.

```js
// "The source are jQuery objects" ~ JKB
var source = $('.my-selector')

/* "This source should be cloned into an array" - JKB
I am Copying this from your original code. */
var myArray = $('.my-selector').clone().toArray()

/* "Now i want to increase the arrays size by copying its content into itself, after that the array should contain 20 objects (each object twice)" - JKB
Our array should contain 6, since we're cloning 3 elements onto itself. Copying this again from your original code. */
var myNewArray = myArray.concat($('.my-selector').clone().toArray())

// "BUT: Now this objects should be inserted back into another DOM place (not into their original place)." - JKB
$('#anotherPlace').append(myNewArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-selector">first</div>
<div class="my-selector">second</div>
<div class="my-selector">third</div>
<div id="anotherPlace" style="background:red"></div>
```

> But it seems that the new arrays elements are references to the
>   original and no real clones.

They aren't, that's why we see 2 copies of each - first, second and third in the red background div. Is this what you were looking for, or did I miss something obvious?

Comment: The source are jQuery objects. This source should be cloned into an array (this works, first code line). Let's say this array contains 10 objects at this moment. Now i want to increase the arrays size by copying its content into itself, after that the array should contain 20 objects (each object twice). BUT: Now this objects should be inserted back into another DOM place (not into their original place).

Comment: @JKB I have updated my answer based on your comment, please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `concat` method on javascript from mdn.

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

`var arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
arr = arr.concat(arr);`

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

using ES6 spread operator you can do:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const doubledArr = [...arr, ...arr]

console.log(doubledArr) // [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the objects to be cloned sequentially, so you could just concatenate the array with a clone of itself using:

`arr = arr.concat(arr)`